# dBase library - trying to delete a record

Tags: python, dbf

im using Python 3.6 and the dbf library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf as well as example file dbase_30.dbf & dbase_30.fpt from https://github.com/infused/dbf/tree/master/spec/fixtures. executing this code results in an error.

```
import dbf

dbase_30 = dbf.Table('dbase_30.dbf')
dbase_30.open()

print("Table size: {}".format(dbase_30.__len__()))

dbase_30[0].delete_record()
```

[image]

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `infused` link is for a Ruby package, so that won't be much help.

- `dbase_30` above is a table;
- `dbase_30[0]` is a record in the table
- the command to delete records is a module level function called `delete`

So, if you want to delete the very first record:

```
dbf.delete(dbase_30[0])
```

This only marks the record as deleted, it doesn't actually remove it.  To remove *all* deleted records:

```
dbase_30.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I realised you are the author of the library. Maybe you should update the documentation because the .delete_record() is still there.